Are these statistical test inappropriate?
I have a dataset with the ages of survey respondents and many answers to the survey. Trying to see if there is a relationship between age and survey response. If one was to do individual parametric or nonparametric tests on each survey response to see what p-values are significant, is that an inappropriate method, rather than using age and all survey responses together?
